Material for learning to use pymatgen?
I was looking for methods to generate the k-path for electronic band calculation in periodic solids. In the article below, the authors presented an algorithm they developed based on the Latimer–Munro (LM) method that can generate the k-paths "on-the-fly":
Article: J.M. Munro, K. Latimer, M.K. Horton, S. Dwaraknath, K.A. Persson, An improved symmetry-based approach to reciprocal space path selection in band structure calculations, npj Computational Materials 6 112 (2020). DOI: 10.1038/s41524-020-00383-7  (Open Access).
From the article:

The outlined algorithm and associated tools have been implemented into the existing portion of the pymatgen software package [16] that handles high-symmetry k-path generation.

As a newbie with pymatgen, after installed it, I went to read the documentation and                search for some examples/tutorials, unsuccessfully. I found the documentations from the pymatgen site hard to use. Even the example site they recommend (Matgenb Examples) have very few Jupiter notebooks.
My question: Do you know any other source from where I can learn to use the pymatgen packages? Specially the k-path generation?
